# How do I remove a task from a workshop's task queue?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I added some tasks to a Carpenter's Workshop that I didn't want.  I don't see any way to modify the tasks in the task queue.  How can I remove these tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the task and press 'c'. This will cancel the selected task, causing the artisan to drop any claimed materials that are being collected.

This works for all workshops.

Comment: Added tip: Hitting 'r' in the task queue lets you set a task to repeat indefinitely.

Comment: Additional tip: If your task was added to the workshop from the Manager menu, canceling it on a workshop is a temporary fix at best, as your manager will re-assign the task.